# Can I pass a radio button value and checkbox values through a URL using Powerforms in Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

Can I pass a radio button value and checkbox values through a URL using Powerforms in DocuSign?

These values would come directly from an application, and I wish to have them auto populate along with the other information from my website when the user clicks to sign I have everything transferring over except the radio buttons and checkbox values.

I have text fields opened where the value should be displayed, and I read you could have those values passed through the URL and shown in the custom fields...not sure how though.

I am also aware you can use the API, but you cannot combine API with the Powerform.

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

General documentation on populating fields through the PowerForm URL is available here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform

Checkboxes can be preselected by setting their value to 'true'. For Radio buttons, it's GroupName=ValueName

so if I have a group of radio buttons labeled "Color" my URL might be `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Signer 1_UserName=Example User&Signer 1_Email=user@example.com&CheckBox=true&Color=Green`

Comment: Thank you for your help but just a couple of questions...Yeah I ran into that page s well, but what if i don't know the value name of what they have selected since the information is supposed to transfer over after they have submitted the application and after they click to sign the pdf (docusing page) I wont know the value they choose before hand..also I understand setting the checkbox value to true, but how is it supposed to appear in the text field I have made specifically for that value on the docusign page?